# Can I get some idea with this haskell exercise?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, axis

I got this exercise, but I do not know how to start and solve it.

Point on one axis

- Determine if a point represented by a coordinate lies on an axis in the coordinate system!
- Use pattern matching! Do not use equality testing or branching.
- Also specify the type of function!
- Each of the following test cases must give a True:
- `onAxis (0, 0)`
- `onAxis (0, 100)`
- `onAxis (50, 0)`
- `onAxis (-12, 0)`
- `not (onAxis (4, 5))`

Comment: Imagine that you should write it in another language you are familiar with (Java/Python/C++ for example). How would you implement such function.

Comment: or in English / any other language.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem probably with equality testing and branching which are prohibited

Comment: @user253751: I would first focus on implementing a solution, then later look what you can use, and rewrite items accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell's pattern matching is a powerful and useful feature. For example, you can have multiple formulas for your function and Haskell will choose the one where, e.g., the argument patterns match:

```
isZero :: Int -> Bool
isZero 0 = True
isZero _ = False
```

This simple little function should just tell me if my argument is equal to Zero. I do this without any comparison, just by pattern matching. `0` matches.. well, literally `0`. But `_` matches *everything*. The order matters here, the first formula to match is chosen.

So what about your points? They are represented as Tuples: `(x, y)`. We can "look into" values with pattern matching:

```
isZeroPoint :: (Int, Int) -> Bool
isZeroPoint (0, 0) = True
isZeroPoint _      = False
```

OK, so how do we know if a (2 dimensional) point is on the X or Y axis? Look at the examples given, it should be quite obvious by now!

With this, you should be able to solve your exercise!
Report back if you did it or still have questions ;)

PS: I'm not spelling out the complete solution, because I don't think it helps you if I do your homework for you.

PPS: I simply chose the concrete type `Int` for simplicity and because I don't know what else about Haskell types you have already learned. One could use a different number type (e.g., `Integer`) or something more general.

Comment: Thank you it is working with this:                                                                             
onAxis :: (Int, Int) -> Bool
onAxis (x,0) =True
onAxis (0,y) =True
onAxis _  =False

Comment: Great, if you don't use a variable you can use a wildcard pattern `_` instead, so `onAxis (_, 0) = True`. You can also define it as `onAxis2 (x, y) = any (== 0) [x, y]`